# Customer Name,Mobile Number and Description Fetch but not fetch address why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['updatecustomer'])){
 $customerID=trim($_POST['customerID']);
 $customername=trim($_POST['customername']);
 $mobilenumber=trim($_POST['mobilenumber']);
 $Description=trim($_POST['description']);
      $area=trim($_POST['area']);


      if(empty($customername)){
          $errorcustomername="Please Enter Customer Name";
      }

      elseif (empty($mobilenumber)) {
        $Errormobilenumber="Please Enter Mobile Number";
      }

      elseif (empty($Description)) {
          $Errordescription="Please Enter Description";
      }


      elseif (empty($area)) {
          $Errorarea="Please Enter Address";
      }


     else
      {

          try {

          if (trim($_FILES["image"]["name"])!=""){
          $base=explode(".", strtolower(basename($_FILES["image"]["name"])));
          $ext=end($base);
          if($ext=="png" or $ext=="jpg" or $ext=="jpeg"){
            $image1 = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            $width = $image1[0];
            $height = $image1[1];
            if($width<256 || $height<256){
                $error = true;
              $ErrorImage = "Please select an image with minimum resolution of 256x256 !";
            }else{

            $image1=uniqid().".".$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "picture/" . $image1);
           $image1="picture/".$image1;
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

/*update Query*/

```
     $sql="UPDATE customer SET shopID='$shopID',name='$customername',
        mobile='$mobilenumber',area='$area',description='$Description',picture='$image1' WHERE customerID='$customerID'";
          $con->exec($sql);

      $sql1="UPDATE customerdetails SET area='$area' WHERE customerID='$customerID' ";
          if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {
            $success="Customer Updated Successfully";
          }
          else
          {

          $errorSubmit="Customer not Updated";
          }

                  }
                }
                   else {
                  }
            $error = true;
            $ErrorImage="invalid image extension !";
          }
          else {
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           $sql="UPDATE customer SET shopID='$shopID',name='$customername',mobile='$mobilenumber,area='$area',description='$Description' WHERE customerID='$customerID'";
          $con->exec($sql);

      $sql1="UPDATE customerdetails SET area='$area' WHERE customerID='$customerID' ";
          if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {
            $success="Customer Updated Successfully";
          }
          else
          {

          $errorSubmit="Customer not Updated";
          }
        }
      }
          catch(PDOException $e)
           {
            $errorSubmit= $e->getMessage();
            } 
   }
      }
?>
<div class="boxed">
<div id="content-container">
<div id="page-title">
<h1 class="page-header text-overflow">Update Customer</h1>

</div>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="Dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a href="customer.php">Customer</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Update Customer</a></li>
</ol>
<div id="page-content">
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 5%">
<div class="panel">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Update Customer Details</h3>
</div>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
```

/*join Query*/

```
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['id']);
 $sql="SELECT customer.*,customerdetails.* FROM customer JOIN customerdetails ON customer.customerID=customerdetails.customerID WHERE customer.customerID='$id'";
$read=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($read)) {
  # code...

?>
<input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="<?php echo $row1['customerID']; ?>">

  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Customer Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" name="customername" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name" value="<?php echo $row1['name']; ?>"
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="60" required="">
<?php if (!empty($errorcustomername)) { ?> <p class="label label-danger"><?php echo $errorcustomernamee; ?></p> <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Mobile Number</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobilenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"  value="<?php echo 
$row1['mobile'];?>" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9- ]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" maxlength="10"/>
<?php if (!empty($Errormobilenumber)) { ?> <p class="label label-danger"><?php echo $Errormobilenumber; ?></p> <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="area" placeholder="Address"  value="<?php echo $row1['area'];?>" />
<?php if (!empty( $Errorarea)) { ?> <p class="label label-danger"><?php echo   $Errorarea; ?></p> <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Description</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="Description"  value="<?php echo $row1['description'];?>" />
<?php if (!empty($Errordescription)) { ?> <p class="label label-danger"><?php echo $Errordescription; ?></p> <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="demo-hor-inputemail">Picture</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" placeholder="Password"  value="<?php echo $row1['image'];?>" 
/>
<?php if (!empty($Errorimage)) { ?> <p class="text text-danger"><?php echo $Errorimage; ?></p> <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<div align="center">
<?php if (!empty($success)) { ?> <span class="label label-success"><?php echo $success; ?></span> <?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($errorSubmit)) { ?> <span class="label label-danger"><?php echo $errorSubmit; ?></span> <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer text-right">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="updatecustomer">Update Customer</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
include 'include/sidebar.php';
include 'include/footer.php';
?>
<?php
}
else
{
  header('location:login.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: var_dump  `$area`to see what is in there

Comment: Please read about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your program is vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

please check first area is inserting to DB or not?